# How I can rewrite this classic Java-code to Java Stream API code?

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

There is a old Java code (without lambda expressions):

```
public List<CheckerPosition> getAttackedCheckersForPoint(CheckerPosition from, boolean isSecondPlayerOwner, boolean isQueen, VectorDirection ignoredDirection){
    List<VectorDirection> allDirections = VectorDirection.generateAllDirections();
    List<CheckerPosition> result = new ArrayList<CheckerPosition>();

    for (VectorDirection direction : allDirections){
        if (!direction.equals(ignoredDirection)){
            Checker firstCheckerOnWay = findFirstCheckerOnWay(new CheckerBaseVector(from, direction), !isQueen);
            if ((firstCheckerOnWay != null) && (firstCheckerOnWay.isSecondPlayerOwner() != isSecondPlayerOwner) && isCheckerBlocked(firstCheckerOnWay.getPosition(), direction)){
                result.add(firstCheckerOnWay.getPosition());
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

I'm trying to rewrite this code to **Java 8 Stream API** style:

```
allDirections.stream()
                .filter(d -> !d.equals(ignoredDirection))
                .map(d -> findFirstCheckerOnWay(new CheckerBaseVector(from, d), !isQueen)) // In this operation I map VectorDirection element (d) to Checker variable type.
                .filter(c -> (c != null) && (c.isSecondPlayerOwner() != isSecondPlayerOwner) && isCheckerBlocked(c.getPosition(), d)); // But in this operation I need to access d variable...
```

**PROBLEM:** The function `isCheckerBlocked()` (which uses in last `filter()` operation) takes variable of `VectorDirection` type (variable `d`). But after calling `map()` function I lose access to this variable. How I can save access to `d` variable after calling `map()` function?

Thank you for attention.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't access `direction` once you've mapped it to a new type. Maybe you can create a new object that encapsulates `VectorDirection` and `Checker` and you can map 'direction' to that type.

Comment: another possibility: in the mapping step, where both c and d are in scope, you could map to null if isCheckerBlocked

Comment: I am not sure if there is a good reason for rewriting it that way. I don't see how it would make the code more readable, mantainable, performant etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot share scopes of lambdas like that. In other languages you can use tuples, so instead of returning just the result, you return result *and* argument.

In java you can create a custom class to host the pair of data you need or create a Tuple to host the pair of data .

```
public class Tuple<A,B> {
    public final A _1;
    public final B _2;
    public Tuple(A a, B b){
        _1 = a;
        _2 = b;
    }
    public static <A,B> Tuple<A,B> tuple(A a, B b){
        return new Tuple<>(a, b);
    }
}
```

Importing the tuple static function like this `import static so.alpha.Tuple.tuple;` you can  `map(tuple(d,f(d))))` then your next function will be `filter(t->p(t._1,t._2))` and then you will `map(t->t._1)` or if you add getters to the tuple you can also `map(Tuple::get_1)`

That way you can carry on your *d* to the next step.

```
    Stream<String> s = Arrays.asList("sa","a","bab","vfdf").stream();

    Stream<Integer> result = s.map(d -> tuple(d.length(),d)) //String to Tuple<Integer,String>
        .filter(t->t._1 >= 2 && t._2.contains("a")) // Filter using both
        .map(Tuple::get_1); // Return just Integers
```